# Overload Resolution failed because

Tags: vb.net

First, I know next to nothing about coding, but...

We have a vb file that we use so users can enter requests which in turn sends emails to various distribution lists.  I did not create this file, it has been here long before I arrived.

It has worked fine until now and "nobody" made any changes.

The error we get is:
error BC30516: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' accepts this number of arguments. msg = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("itrequest@bnhc.org")

The code goes like this:
       ' third Message

```
    msg = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("itrequest@******.org")
    msg.IsBodyHtml = True
    subj = "New Hire Form Confirmation"
```

There are two other emails before this one, both coded the same way, just different destinations.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You might be interested in something called [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control). It comes with more recent versions of Visual Studio - you would want the GitHub Extension for Visual Studio. (If you find tutorials that write about Visual Studio Team Services (or similar), it is now called Azure DevOps.) By using version control, you can go back through previous versions of code, and the remote repository means that you have a remote backup of it too.

Answer (score 0):

If this was working before then someone definitely modified it. You are creating an Instance MailMessage() without providing all of the parameters

```
msg = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("itrequest@******.org")
```

lists the sending email only however MailMessage requires a sending and receiving email

```
Dim msg = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("itrequest@******.org", "recipient@google.com")
```

replace recipient@google.com with your email recipient and you will no longer have this issue
I hope this helps

Comment: James, you win the Internets today!  Thank you sir, Happy New Year!

Comment: @BobRoss The best way to thank someone on Stack Overflow is to accept their answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer. If you have enough reps you can also upvote with the triangle above the 0.

Comment: @BobRoss If you want to see the other overloads navigate to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage?view=netframework-4.8 and scroll down to Constructors. You can see vb code by selecting it at the top with the language drop down.

Comment: @BobRoss we're still in 2019 over here:)